# asp.net web config authorization sub folders

Tags: asp.net, security, web-config

I want to check under the parent folder and all folders but it does not.

```
<location path="admins">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="Admin"/>
    <deny users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Parent folder OK. but sub folder everyone to public

Comment: Have you referred to this link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12917564/asp-net-web-config-authorization-settings-ignored-in-subfolders

Comment: So they can access a subfolder? Is there a web.config in that subfolder? What are they accessing? A web page? A PDF?