# How do I block access to certain URLs with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, security, url

I want to block access to `/admins/setting.txt` and to `/user_N/setting.txt` from browsers.

Where can I control these requests?

Comment: From being served? Or do you mean authentication? Clarify...otherwise, your question will likely be closed...

Comment: Need any more help with this? If so I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add such settings to your `web.config` file, like this:

For a specific file:

```
<location path="admins/setting.txt">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

For a folder

```
<location path="user_N">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Static files aren't going to be affected by this unless he adds a handler for them, as I answered [in this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21965927/1810243). I think this is related to [his previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28999806/1810243) but he never answer my questions.

Answer (score 0):

Move the folder to one under `App_Data`.

e.g.

```
example.com/App_Data/admins/setting.txt
```

This will prevent the files from being served.